# Bison/Flex practicing with the language of palindrome strings

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex

I'm practising with Bison and Flex. My goal is to create a parser for the language of the palindrome strings. This is my very simple `.l` file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "G1.tab.h"
%}

%%

"a" { return (A);}
"b" { return (B);}

%%
```

And this is my `.y` file:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>

int yylex();
int yyerror(char *s);

%}

%token A B 

%%

prog:
  srule
;

srule   
    : A srule A
    | B srule B
    | A A
    | B B
    | A
    | B
;

%%

int yyerror(char *s){
  printf("\nParsing result:  %s\n\n", s);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int parse = yyparse();
    if(parse == 0) printf("\nParsing result:  SUCCESS\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I try `ababbbbaba` or `baabaaaaabaab` that are correct strings it returns Syntax Error. I think that maybe there is a problem with the grammar but doing the same experiment with Antlr it works.

Now, I know that Antlr works Top-Down and Bison Bottom-Up, but this couldn't be a problem.
Can anyone explain the problem to me? Thank you.

Comment: Surely bison reports a shift-reduce conflict, no?

Comment: Yes, `6 shift/reduce` and `2 reduce/reduce`.
Is it possible that bison cannot solve them and therefore I have to manipulate the grammar?

Comment: you should always mention things like that in your questions about grammars. Although I suppose in this case it is so obvious that no one is going to be confused. Bison cannot solve these conflicts because there is no solution.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this topic. Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

That grammar cannot be parsed using a left-to-right parser because there is no way to know when to apply the non-recursive productions without knowing how long the input is.

Comment: Thank you very much